# noetherian rings $R \subset S$

Tags: ring-theory

Let $R \subset S$ be rings.

assume that S is finitly generated over R. 
The book i'm reading states that if R is a noetherian R, than S is noetherian as wel. But their is no proof of this given.

I don't see why... can someone help me with this?

Comment: This is Hilbert's basis theorem. [here is a link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert%27s_basis_theorem).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume $R$ is noetherian and $S=R[a_1,...,a_n]$.

By Hilbert's basis theorem, any polynomial ring over a noetherian ring is noetherian, so $R[X_1,...,X_n]$ is a noetherian ring since $R$ is. Then $S=R[X_1,...,X_n]/(X_1-a_1,...,X_n-a_n)$ is a quotient of noetherian rings and therefore noetherian.